# unexpected memory corruption in baremetal environment [SOLVED]

Tags: c, operating-system, bootloader, bare-metal, linker-scripts

i have a simple 32 bit kernel which gets loaded succesfully by a bootloader shown below

```
[org 0x7c00]
; we can also alter the data segment register (ds) accordingly:
; mov ds, 0x7c0 (it will be 0x7c00 because address bus is 20-bit)

KERNEL_LOCATION equ 0x1000
BOOT_DISK equ 0

; setting up the stack and tiny memory model
xor ax, ax
mov es, ax
mov ds, ax
mov bp, 0x8000
mov sp, bp


; loading the kernel in memory location 0x1000
call read_disk

; ; Set up VESA graphics mode (example: mode 0x101 - 640x480, 16 colors)
; mov ax, 0x4F02     ; VESA function to set video mode
; mov bx, 0x101      ; Mode number for desired resolution/color depth
; int 0x10           ; Call BIOS interrupt to set the video mode

; initialize protected mode
init_pm:

    ; clear the screen using bios before disabling it
    mov ax, 0x0003 
    int 10h

    ; clear interrupts
    mov bx,suc
    ;call print_string
    
    ; some delay just for looking cool :)
    ;call delay
    ;mov ax, 0x0003
    ;int 10h
 
    cli
    ; this instruction loads the gdt location and size into the gdtr (gdt register) in the cpu
    lgdt [GDT_descriptor]

    ; changing the first bit of cr0 register (0th control register) which corresponds to [ Protected Mode Enable ]
    mov eax, cr0
    or eax, 1
    mov cr0, eax

    ; far jump!!
    jmp CODE_SEG:start_protected_mode

%include "gdt.asm"
%include "read_disk.asm"
;%include "print_string.asm"
%include "delay.asm"

; this tells the assembeler (in this case nasm) to compile the
; code to 32 bit machine code now on
[bits 32]
start_protected_mode:

    ; changing stack and memory segments model
    mov eax, DATA_SEG
    mov ds, eax
    mov ss, eax
    mov es, eax
    mov fs, eax
    mov gs, eax

    mov ebp, 0x90000        ; 32 bit stack base pointer
    mov esp, ebp

    jmp KERNEL_LOCATION

suc:
    db "entering 32-bit mode...",0
jmp $



times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

my problem is that my kernel .text section will overwrite other parts of my kernel therefore leading to random behaviors

here is the kernel code written in c:

```c
#include "std/stdout.h"
#include "terminal/terminal.h"



void func1(){
        for (int i = 0; i < 33; i++)
    {
        /* code */
    }
}
void func2(){
        for (int i = 0; i < 33; i++)
    {
        /* code */
    }
}
void func3(){
        for (int i = 0; i < 33; i++)
    {
        /* code */
    }
}
void func4(){
    for (int i = 0; i < 33; i++)
    {
        /* code */
    }
    
}


void kernel_start(){
    prepare_terminal();
    background_color = 32;
}
```

NOTE: somehow only having 3 of those funcs doesnt cause the problem so i suspect adding one more is exceeding some kind of limit

i tried changing the linker script to add alignments as i suspected its due to the limited size of each section but it didnt helped or maybe i did it wrong

here is my current linker script:

```
ENTRY(_start)

SECTIONS {
    . = 0x1000;

    .text : {
        *(.text)
    }
    
    .data : {
        *(.data)
    }

    .bss : {
        *(.bss)
    }
}
```

broken code:
[image: normal]

normal:
[image: broken code]

Comment: Put your kernel to be loaded at address ```0x100000``` not ```0x1000```. You set your kernel at ```Real mode address space (the first MiB)```.

Comment: i changed KERNEL_LOCATION to  0x100000
but now it wont even load my kernel

im loading the kernel in real mode using bios functions so i can only address up to 16 bits

Comment: The first problem is that you have no idea what `SS` is when you set `SP` to 0x8000, so all the writes (and reads) from the stack (at `SS:SP`) are going to an unknown address. Note that if `SS:SP` happened to be `0x0000:0x8000` by accident (which is potentially more likely than other values) then you'd have 512 bytes of stack before the stack overwrites your code, and the BIOS functions used by `read_disk` are likely to use more stack than that, so that may not end well.

Comment: @Brendan the problem is that it happened by defining the functions not calling them

Comment: @alireza: My main problems are that your code is buggy, if all the bugs were fixed the entire thing would still be obsolete, and to actually make any of it useful you'd have to redesign and rewrite then entire thing so none of the code matters; and I can't see important parts (e.g. `read_disk` to determine if the kernel is loaded or just a "too little" 512 bytes); but when I scan through the code like a CPU would I find a major bug in the first 10 instructions, and then I give up because it's like searching for a piece of hay in a large pile of needles while blind-folded.

Comment: @alireza: Note that a kernel will need a memory map (from BIOS functions), a modern monolithic kernel will grow to be larger than "real mode accessible RAM", a floppy boot sector needs a "BIOS Parameter Block" and a hard disk boot sector needs to care about partitions (and boot from the correct partition); and (even without useful error messages or adequate sanity checks) these will force you to need more than 1 sector of (real mode) boot code for whatever you think the boot code is supposed to be booting from.

Answer (score 1):

So, it turned out my problem was because I was only reading 10 sectors from the disk, which caused the program to stop halfway and create some unexpected issues.

What I did was increase the number of sectors to be read:

```
read_disk:

    ; bios read functions
    mov ah, 0x02

    ; number of sectors to be read
    ; mov al, 10                    <========! HERE
    mov al, 40    

    ; chs addressing
    mov ch, 0x00 ; cylender
    mov dh, 0x00 ; head
    mov cl, 0x02 ; sector (reading the first sector after the boot sector sectors start at 1)


    ; setting the bx to the address we want to load our read disk
    mov bx, KERNEL_LOCATION

    mov dl, BOOT_DISK

    int 0x13  
    ; jump to error handler if c flag is one
    ; jc disk_error

    ; returning to the caller address
    ret

; error handler
disk_error:
    mov bx, error_msg
    ;call print_string
    jmp $

error_msg:
    ; null terminating string :)
    db "error reading disk",0
```

and it solved my problem :)